# C++ if statement seems to ignore the argument

Tags: function, if-statement, arguments

Here's the code.

```
bool b_div(int n_dividend)
{
    for (int iii = 10 ; iii>0 ; iii--)
    {
        int n_remainder = n_dividend%iii;
        if (n_remainder != 0)
         return false;
        if (iii = 1)
         return true;

    }
}
```

After testing this function I made for a program, the function seems to stop at the if (n_remainder != 0) part. Now then the function SHOULD test if the number that the function takes in can be divided by all numbers from 10 to 1.(it takes in numbers until it returns true) I know the first number that this works with it is 2520 but even on this number it stops at if(n_remainder != 0). So I was hoping for some advice! Im having trouble troubleshooting it! Any links or words I should look for would be awesome! Im still pretty new to programming so any help you can give for learning would rock! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your last if statement to:

```
if (iii == 1)
  return true;
```

Currently you have only a single equals sign, which sets the variable iii to 1, and is always true. By using a double equals it will compare iii and 1.

Comment: Good call.  One common style is to put the constant on the left-hand-side so you'd get a compile time error, avoiding this type of mistake.  This would look like: if (1 == iii) ...

Comment: Some folks have been known to put the literal on the left in `if` statements, so that if you forget the second `=`, the compiler will spit out an error instead of going on its merry way. However, I once saw a compiler that accepted that and turned every literal `1` in the entire program into the contents of `iii`. :-(

Comment: Okay so I added the extra = to it but I still have the problem, this program ALWAYS enters that first if statement, even if n_remainder = 0. So I need to figure out why it enters that no matter what! Also thanks for the advice on the missing =. I totally didn't see that! Thanks!

Comment: I just ran your code with the fixed == and it does not enter the first if statement on n_dividend = 2520. Are you sure that 2520 is getting passed in correctly?

Comment: Okay so he was right, what happened is sometimes, if I don't restart my IDE it doesn't like register I re-wrote some code. So once I restarted my IDE his fixed worked magic! Awesome! thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to SC Ghost's answer, you can actually also clean up your function a bit more :)

```
bool b_div(int n_dividend) {
    for (int i = 10 ; i > 1 ; i--) {
        int n_remainder = n_dividend % i;
        if (n_remainder != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

A few notes,

1. modulus of 1 will always be zero, so you only need to iterate while `i > 1`
2. you can completely remove the `if(i == 1)` check and just always `return true` after the for loop if the for loop doesn't `return false`. It basically removes an unnecessary check.
3. I think it's more standard to name your iterator `iii` as `i`, And I prefer brackets the way I wrote them above (this is of course completely personal preference, do as you please)

Comment: Thanks. Now then Ive had a lot of advice from various people on naming the iterator. So far people have suggested i, iii, or ndx. Im wondering which one is the standard?

Comment: single letters, like `i`, or if it's a nested for loop `i` then `j` are standard I would say.